# iText manipulate pdf with non-embedded fonts stored on file system

Tags: itext

Using iText, need help to apply existing pdf with non-embedded fonts stored on file system.
a. I have pdf documents with non-embedded fonts (pdf include the name of the font). I have all these non-embedded fonts available on file system.
b. I need to modify the existing pdf by applying these fonts.

Can someone please help in providing a working code snippet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify: are you saying that you need to embed fonts in a PDF where these fonts aren't embedded? (If so, why didn't you say so?) Right now, your question is unclear. For instance: what have you tried? Did you try this: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=288

Comment: I have a set of PDF files which I have got from AFP file using the tool CrawFord. When Splitting the AFP file I haven't applied fonts as we don't have required license. Now when we opened the pdf file I found the pdf file has missing fonts. I am trying to find a way if we can apply the fonts using iText? Wanted to know if this is feasible at first place.

Comment: It is possible to embed fonts that aren't embedded in many cases, but not in all cases. It depends on the type of font that needs to be embedded and the encoding that was used in the original document. If a custom encoding was used, it can be very hard. Try the example I referred to and experiment with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.Will try and post my results. Thanks again.